# El contenido de los 'divs' se sobrepasan de su tamaño

Tags: html, css

He hecho una página sencilla, la cual el contenido de los **divs** se sobrepasan de su tamaño dentro del segundo **article**.

**Esta imagen refleja un zoom de 25% de la pagina original que es del 100%.**
[image: Esta imagen refleja un zoom de 25%]

Comment: Cuando dices descalabar, es porque se solaplan los divs o porque no te aparece un scroll cuando el contenido sobre pasa el tamaño del div? Mira este ejemplo en js bin y dime si esto es lo que quieres http://jsbin.com/lijagigufu/edit?output

Comment: @Einer - El contenido se sobrepasa el tamaño del div.

Comment: Y que quieres hacer en ese caso? Agregar un scroll vertical o que el div sea del tamaño del contenido?

Comment: que los divs sean el tamaño del contenido.

Comment: No veo en el snippet de tu código que el comportamiento sea el que dices. Tampoco veo ningún elemento con la clase `city`.

Comment: '.city' no se llama, se llama '.tres'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifica el css `.tres`

```
.tres {
   display:inline-block;
   margin: 0.1%;
   max-width: 202px;
   max-height: 300px;
}
```

Se retira el `float:left` porque lo hace flotante y se baja un poco el `max-width` (podrías usar porcentajes también) para que entren las 3 columnas.

Tu codigo original no debería tener problemas con el zoom al 100%. En todo caso el ajuste que propongo funciona para todos los porcentajes.

Comment: Si te ha servido dale +1 y márcala cómo válida, si no contácteme por los comentarios

Answer (score 0):

**Con este index y css no debiera ocurrir eso, a continuacion dejo fotos de como se ve.**
[image: Vista]

**index.html**  //tienes un `<ul>` sin cerrar

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
            <title>zxczxc</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="description" content="Web Page">
            <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS">
            <meta name="author" content="sdfgaa">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
        <header id="banner">
        <img src="img/xx.jpg">
        <div class="continente">
         <p><span>bdsasdfa</span></p>      
        </div>       
         <nav class="menu">
          <a href="#">fhfghf</a>
          <a href="i.html" target="_blank">dhfshsgf</a>
          <a href="#">sfsdf</a>
          <a href="fo.html" target="_blank">sfsdfs</a>
         </nav>
</header>
<main class="group">
 <section id="blog">
  <div class="contenedor">
   <article class="tamanio1">
                    <h1>adadasdasdas</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
                          turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
                          ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
                          et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
                          dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
                          nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
                          Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
                          dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
                          turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
                          ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
                          et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
                          dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
                          nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
                          Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
                          dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
                          turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
                          ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
                          et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
                          dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
                          nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
                          Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
                          dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
   </article>

   <article class="tamanio2">
                    <h1>asdfasd</h1>
                    <p class="margen-parrafo">El contenido de este libro se estructura en tres apartados bien diferenciados: </p>

                        <div class="tres">
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
                          turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
                          ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
                          et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
                          dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
                          nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
                          Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
                          dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tres">
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
                          turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
                          ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
                          et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
                          dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
                          nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
                          Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
                          dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tres">
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
                          turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
                          ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
                          et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
                          dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
                          nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
                          Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
                          dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
                        </div>
   </article>
 </div>     
</section>

 <aside id="aside">
                  <article class="hola">
                        <h3>Info</h3>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">nujh</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sfsdf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sdfsdf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sfsdfs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">dfsfsds</a></li>
                      </ul>                     
                  </article>

                  <article class="adios">
                        <img src="./img/xxx.jpg">
                        <h1 class="xao">holakaspoasd</h1>
                  </article>
 </aside>
</main>

 <div class="clear"></div>

<footer>
         <p>&copy; copyright 203123. Drechos Reservados</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main.css**    //agregue propiedades a li, .menu y #banner

```
*{   
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: myFuente;
        src: url(../fonts/Respective_Slanted.ttf);
    }

    body{
        border: 2px solid black; 
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
        background: white;
        max-width:960px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    .group {
        position: relative;
        background:white;
    }

    .group:before,
    .group:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
    }
    .group:after {
      clear: both;
    }
    .group {
      clear: both;
    }
    section {
      float: right;
      margin: 3% 2%;
      width: 65%;
    }
    aside {
      float: left;
      margin: 3% 2%;
      width: 27%;
    }


    main .clear {
        clear: both;
    }

    footer {
           margin:1px auto;
           clear: both;
    }


        #blog {
    position: relative;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio1 h1{
     font-size:x-large;
     margin-bottom:3%;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio2 h1{
     font-size:x-large;
     margin-top:3%;
     margin-bottom:3%;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio2 .margen-parrafo {
     margin-bottom:3%;
}

.tres {
   float: left;
   margin: 0.1%;
   max-width: 206px;
   max-height: 300px;
}
```

> DIVS

```
#blog {
    position: relative;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio1 h1{
     font-size:x-large;
     margin-bottom:3%;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio2 h1{
     font-size:x-large;
     margin-top:3%;
     margin-bottom:3%;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio2 .margen-parrafo {
     margin-bottom:3%;
}

.city {
   float: left;
   margin: 0.1%;
   max-width: 206px;
   max-height: 300px;
    }  
li{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.menu{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#banner{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Primero que nada:** Muy mal planteada la pregunta; no se sabe que esperas obtener y no se entiende bien que estás haciendo. En ningún elemento se usa la clase `.city` que a tu entender se está "descabalando".

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para solucionar el problema (asumiendo que he entendido lo que quieres) solo tienes que darle una altura máxima y un comportamiento a la propiedad `overflow` a todos los artículos que sean del tipo problemático; logro identificarlos porque usan la clase `tamanio2`. Lo he resuelto agregando la siguiente regla CSS que puedes ver en acción en el código de abajo:

```
 #blog .contenedor .tamanio2 {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```css
*{   
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
         font-size: 15px;
        }
        
        @font-face {
            font-family: myFuente;
            src: url(../fonts/Respective_Slanted.ttf);
        }
        
        body{
         border: 2px solid black; 
         font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
         background: white;
         max-width:960px;
         margin:0 auto;
        }
        
        .group {
         position: relative;
         background:white;
        }
        
        .group:before,
        .group:after {
          content: "";
          display: table;
        }
        .group:after {
          clear: both;
        }
        .group {
          clear: both;
        }
        section {
          float: right;
          margin: 3% 2%;
          width: 65%;
        }
        aside {
          float: left;
          margin: 3% 2%;
          width: 27%;
        }
        
        
        main .clear {
         clear: both;
        }
        
        footer {
               margin:1px auto;
               clear: both;
        }
        
        
            #blog {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #blog .contenedor .tamanio1 h1{
      font-size:x-large;
         margin-bottom:3%;
    }

    #blog .contenedor .tamanio2 h1{
      font-size:x-large;
         margin-top:3%;
         margin-bottom:3%;
    }
    
    #blog .contenedor .tamanio2 .margen-parrafo {
         margin-bottom:3%;
    }
    
    .tres {
       float: left;
       margin: 0.1%;
       max-width: 206px;
       max-height: 300px;
    }   

> DIVS
   
    #blog {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #blog .contenedor .tamanio1 h1{
      font-size:x-large;
         margin-bottom:3%;
    }
    
    #blog .contenedor .tamanio2 {
      max-height: 200px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    #blog .contenedor .tamanio2 h1{
      font-size:x-large;
         margin-top:3%;
         margin-bottom:3%;
    }
    
    #blog .contenedor .tamanio2 .margen-parrafo {
         margin-bottom:3%;
    }
    
    .city {/*ESTA PARTE DE ME DESCABALA HACIA ABAJO*/
       float: left;
       margin: 0.1%;
       max-width: 206px;
       max-height: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
           <title>zxczxc</title>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="description" content="Web Page">
       <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS">
       <meta name="author" content="sdfgaa">
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="css2/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <header id="banner">
      <img src="img/xx.jpg">
      <div class="continente">
          <p><span>bdsasdfa</span></p>    
      </div>   
             <nav class="menu">
              <a href="#">fhfghf</a>
              <a href="i.html" target="_blank">dhfshsgf</a>
              <a href="#">sfsdf</a>
        <a href="fo.html" target="_blank">sfsdfs</a>
             </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="group">
     <section id="blog">
      <div class="contenedor">
       <article class="tamanio1">
                        <h1>adadasdasdas</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
            turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
            ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
            et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
            dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
            nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
            Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
            dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
            turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
            ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
            et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
            dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
            nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
            Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
            dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
            turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
            ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
            et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
            dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
            nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
            Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
            dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
       </article>
         
       <article class="tamanio2">
         <h1>asdfasd</h1>
         <p class="margen-parrafo">El contenido de este libro se estructura en tres apartados bien diferenciados: </p>
          
          <div class="tres">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
            turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
            ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
            et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
            dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
            nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
            Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
            dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
          </div>
    
          <div class="tres">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
            turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
            ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
            et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
            dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
            nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
            Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
            dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
          </div>
    
          <div class="tres">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et 
            turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu 
            ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus 
            et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent non velit 
            dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae 
            nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. 
            Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in 
            dolor eget sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
          </div>
       </article>
     </div>  
    </section>
    
     <aside id="aside">
          <article class="hola">
          <h3>Info</h3>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">nujh</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sfsdf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sdfsdf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sfsdfs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dfsfsds</a></li>
          <ul>      
          </article>
          
          <article class="adios">
             <img src="./img/xxx.jpg">
                            <h1 class="xao">holakaspoasd</h1>
          </article>
     </aside>
    </main>
    
     <div class="clear"></div>
    
    <footer>
       <p>&copy; copyright 203123. Drechos Reservados</p>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Lee los comentarios esta mas que claro un 'scroll' no es lo que busco : El contenido se sobrepasa el tamaño del div. '.city' no se llama se llama '.tres'.

Comment: Las solicitudes de aclaración/mejora de publicaciones se hacen en comentarios, no en las respuestas, por otro lado en [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) se recomienda responder sólo las preguntas bien formuladas, por lo que si parece que la pregunta no es buena, no se debería responder.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aqui esta con el 25% de zoom, creo que eso entendi. 
Solo modifique la clase .tres de tu css, y le aplique un margen a tus ul > li

Espero te sirva

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: myFuente;
  src: url(../fonts/jjh.tff);
}

body {
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
  background: white;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.group:after {
  clear: both;
}

.group {
  clear: both;
}

section {
  float: right;
  margin: 3% 2%;
  width: 65%;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3% 2%;
  width: 27%;
}

ul li {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

main .clear {
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  margin: 1px auto;
  clear: both;
}

#blog {
  position: relative;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio1 h1 {
  font-size: x-large;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio2 h1 {
  font-size: x-large;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio2 .margen-parrafo {
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.tres {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.1%;
  max-width: 202px;
  max-height: 300px;
}

#blog {
  position: relative;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio1 h1 {
  font-size: x-large;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio2 h1 {
  font-size: x-large;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#blog .contenedor .tamanio2 .margen-parrafo {
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.city {
  /*ESTA PARTE DE ME DESCABALA HACIA ABAJO*/
  float: left;
  margin: 0.1%;
  max-width: 206px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="banner">
    <img src="img/xx.jpg">
    <div class="continente">
      <p><span>bdsasdfa</span></p>
    </div>
    <nav class="menu">
      <a href="#">fhfghf</a>
      <a href="i.html" target="_blank">dhfshsgf</a>
      <a href="#">sfsdf</a>
      <a href="fo.html" target="_blank">sfsdfs</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="group">
    <section id="blog">
      <div class="contenedor">
        <article class="tamanio1">
          <h1>adadasdasdas</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            Praesent non velit dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in dolor eget sodales.
            Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            Praesent non velit dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in dolor eget sodales.
            Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            Praesent non velit dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in dolor eget sodales.
            Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
        </article>

        <article class="tamanio2">
          <h1>asdfasd</h1>
          <p class="margen-parrafo">El contenido de este libro se estructura en tres apartados bien diferenciados: </p>

          <div class="tres">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
              egestas. Praesent non velit dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in dolor eget
              sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="tres">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
              egestas. Praesent non velit dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in dolor eget
              sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="tres">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et turpis nisi. In pulvinar vitae magna id tempus. Quisque tristique eu ligula quis pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
              egestas. Praesent non velit dapibus, hendrerit urna et, ultricies quam. Ut euismod velit vitae nisl dictum pellentesque. Phasellus venenatis convallis fringilla. Mauris ut dictum dolor, lobortis placerat risus. Mauris blandit in dolor eget
              sodales. Nulla quis orci quis orci blandit vulputate.</p>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>

    <aside id="aside">
      <article class="hola">
        <h3>Info</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">nujh</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sfsdf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sdfsdf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sfsdfs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dfsfsds</a></li>
        </ul>
      </article>

      <article class="adios">
        <img src="./img/xxx.jpg">
        <h1 class="xao">holakaspoasd</h1>
      </article>
    </aside>
  </main>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; copyright 203123. Drechos Reservados</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```